# Errors when coding a Pygame RPG

Tags: pygame

I have a problem with the following code:

---

```css
import pygame, sys, time
from scripts.UltraColor import *

pygame.init()

cSec = 0
cFrame = 0
FPS = 0

fps_font = pygame.font.Font("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Verdana.ttf", 20)


def show_fps():
    fps_overlay = fps_font.render(str(FPS), True, color.Goldenrod)
    window.blit(fps_overlay, (0, 0))


def create_window():
    global window, window_height, window_width, window_title
    window_width, window_height = 1280, 720
    window_title = "The Adventure of Nate"
    pygame.display.set_caption(window_title)
    window = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width, window_height, pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF))


def count_fps():
    global cSec, cFrame, FPS

    if cSec == time.strftime("%S"):
        cFrame += 1

    else:
        FPS = cFrame
        cFrame = 0
        cSec = time.strftime("%S")


create_window()

isrunning = True

while isrunning == True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            isrunning = False

    # LOGIC

    count_fps()

    # Rendering Graphics

    window.fill(color.Black)

    show_fps()

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

---

This code returns the following error:

C:\Python3.6\python.exe "C:/Users/home/PycharmProjects/Basic RPG/Base Game.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/home/PycharmProjects/Basic RPG/Base Game.py", line 38, in 
    create_window()
  File "C:/Users/home/PycharmProjects/Basic RPG/Base Game.py", line 23, in create_window
    window = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width, window_height, pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF))
TypeError: argument 1 must be sequence of length 2, not 3

Process finished with exit code 1

---

If anyone knows how to correct this code, can you please reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in [the documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode), `set_mode` function takes a tuple `(width, height)` and other parameters. You are passing a single tuple. The correct code should look like this (notice the parentheses):

```
window = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width, window_height), pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am such a noob at coding so, I can see if I would miss something like this.